# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance' in Locust

Tags: python, odoo, load-testing, locust

I need to loadtest an Odoo Environment and I have written a test class with different methods in it. Currently I'm trying to test this stuff locally but I'm running in a error that I don't understand right now.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 908, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/home/jhoffmann/ametras_odoo_stress_testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/users.py", line 175, in run_user
    user.run()
  File "/home/jhoffmann/ametras_odoo_stress_testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/users.py", line 143, in run
    self._taskset_instance.run()
  File "/home/jhoffmann/ametras_odoo_stress_testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 365, in run
    self.wait()
  File "/home/jhoffmann/ametras_odoo_stress_testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 443, in wait
    self._sleep(self.wait_time())
  File "/home/jhoffmann/ametras_odoo_stress_testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 418, in wait_time
    return self.user.wait_time()
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'
2022-10-20T11:30:13Z <Greenlet at 0x7f49e55376a0: run_user(<__main__.OdooTestCasesUser object at 0x7f49e51f46)> failed with TypeError
```

I have written the following test classes

```
class OdooTestCases(TaskSet):
    weight = 10
    fixed_count = 1
    min_wait = 0.5
    max_wait = 5.0


    @task(20)
    def read_partners(self):
        customer_model = self.client.get_model("res.partner")
        customer_ids = customer_model.search([], limit=80)

    @task(10)
    def read_product_template_qty(self):
        customer_model = self.client.get_model("product.template")
        customer_ids = customer_model.search([], limit=80)

    @task(10)
    def read_sale_orders(self):
        so_model = self.client.get_model("sale.order")
        so_ids = so_model.search([], limit=100)

    @task(20)
    def read_stock_pickings(self):
        stock_picking_model = self.client.get_model("stock.picking")
        stock_pickings = stock_picking_model.search([], limit=100)

    @task(20)
    def read_stock_movings(self):
        stock_moving_model = self.client.get_model("stock.move")
        stock_movings = stock_moving_model.search([], limit=100)

    @task(30)
    def read_stock_locations(self):
        stock_location_model = self.client.get_model("stock.location")
        stock_locations = stock_location_model.search([], limit=100)

    @task(25)
    def read_stock_picking_types(self):
        stock_picking_type_model = self.client.get_model("stock.picking.type")
        stock_picking_types = stock_picking_type_model.search([], limit=100)

    def stop(self):
        self.interrupt()



class OdooTestCasesUser(OdooLocustUser):
    wait_time = between(0.500, 5)
    host = "localhost"
    database = "demo"
    login = "test"
    password = "test"

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.login = "test"
        self.password = "test"
        self.wait_time = between(0.500, 5)
        self.tasks = [OdooTestCases]
```

Another problem is that I don't get test results returned on my CLI.
I tried everything to fix this, what I've found on the internet, but without any success.
I would be really happy if someone could give me a guess or a solution.
Just hit me up if someone needs more information about this case.

Comment: This is quite a lot of code. Could you create a [mre]? And please ask only one question at a time. Thanks.

Comment: What is `OdooLocustUser`? Is there a ready you're defining all that stuff in `__init__()`? Seems redundant and opens you up to problems.

Comment: OdooLocustUser is the parent class for my user class to make Odoo-Apps testable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using legacy style wait times:

```
min_wait = 0.5
max_wait = 5.0
```

AND new style

```
wait_time = ...
```

Maybe remove the legacy ones?